# Use wired LAN network interface for Teamviewer and Wi-Fi interface for everything else

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, vnc

I need to make TeamViewer use my wired network card and web browsing traffic to use my Wi-Fi network card. I am using Windows XP. How can I make this happen?

If the scenario above would not be possible, would it be possible to use a VNC server and setup IP routing for the VNC connection? But I would still need to tell the OS which network interface to use as default.

Comment: it all comes down to ip routing. are all your teamviewer targets on a known lan that you would never want to access via wifi, even just for passing through?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that TeamViewer needs to connect to different sites than your web browsing traffic, the easy way to do this is probably to do this with routing.  Presumably your wired network connection and your Wi-Fi network connections have different subnets.  Make a note of what your default gateway is for the wired connection.  Then remove the Default Gateway from your wired network card, and web browsing will use Wi-Fi.  Add a custom route for the remote TeamViewer systems; direct such traffic to the address which was your default gateway for the wired connection.

e.g. in Microsoft Windows (which this question was tagged with): `ROUTE ADD 192.0.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1` (if 192.168.0.1 is your default gateway).

This is a kind of sloppy approach, as it would affect other software too.  The less sloppy approach is to find settings in the software (like TeamViewer, or the web browser) that specify what network card to use.  That approach, however, relies on specific options within the software.  A lot of software might not even have such an option, and simply relies on routing rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be achieved using the built-in tools there is a third-party tool that can do that.

ForceBindIP is a command line utility that allows you to easily bind a selected application with an IP or network adapter. In order to use ForceBindIP, you will need to know the IP address of the network adapter that you want to use to bind and the full path to the application. You can type `ipconfig` in command prompt to show the IP address of your network adapters.